Python regex to get data and space only within nested bracket
Input
; (Col1 Col2 (Col3 Col4 Col5) ) 

I need to get the space between Col3 Col4 Col4
Demo
"\(.+\(([^()]*)\)\)*"gm

; (113 (1 2 3) )

I have managed to get the whole (1 2 3). But, how to get just the space in between?
The idea is to get the output:
; (113 (123) )


The regexp in the demo is not the same as what you posted here.

A regular expression can only match a contiguous substring. So it can't remove the spaces.

you keep saying "get the space", but it seems like you want to remove the spaces.

Depending on how generalizable is your need to remove spaces between the values, you could possibly use lookbehind and lookahead checks, to only remove a space when surrounded by alphanumerical characters:
import re
string = "; (113 (1 2 3) )"
pattern = r"(?<=\w) (?=\w)"
result = re.sub(pattern, "", string)
assert result == "; (113 (123) )"

Note that this would also concatenate Col1 and Col2 in your first input, but you might be able to first match the innermost parenthesis with another regex (r"\([^\(]+?\)")
